# Docker Stack deploy compose not working right

Tags: docker, docker-compose, stack

I recently started in with docker and so far have had really good luck with the basics on singular docker servers. My issue comes when I try to use Docker swarm and specifically docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml. I made a simple request (httpd image see below). If I launch this with docker-compose, I get the "It works" page. If I use it with the stack it says it is up and replicated, but I cannot get to it with any address in the cluser. Any advice would be great.

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    image: httpd:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 4
    ports:
      - "8082:80"
```

In terms of troubleshooting:

I ensured the mapped ports were indeed opened on all my docker swarm nodes. I have gone back and used docker-compose to ensure that the system works as expected on a single host and it does. Finally I have ensured that my port mapping in the docker compose is correct and has no conflicts with any other container or port mapping. As I stated, I am rather new to docker and it SEEMS like it is working but I am just not hitting some small thing that prevents me from seeing it work right.

Comment: In terms of a simple compose file like this, it should work. Please add the actual diagnostic steps you have taken.

Comment: Make sure you have swarm enabled:
`docker info | grep Swarm`  to check if swarm is active
if not use `docker swarm init ` to active docker swarm mode

Comment: Having same issue.. Any update on this? Have done this successfully before..